# Unityでベイクしたライトが一部真っ黒になる

Tags: unity3d

UnityでProBuilderを使用して作ったステージ内に、複数のモデルを配置したものを作っています。
ライトは「Realtime」のものと「Baked」のものがそれぞれ複数あり、ベイクしています。
WebGLにビルドし、ブラウザでプレイします。

エディタ上でプレイする分には全く問題なく動いています（画像①）
しかし、ビルドしてブラウザで実行すると、一部の壁や天井が真っ黒になり、反対の壁が余計に明るくなってしまいます。（画像②）

また、ビルドした直後もエディタ上で同様に暗く表示されます。（画像③）
エディタ上のどこかをクリック（Unityをアクティブにする）と戻ります。（画像④）

・数日前まではブラウザでも問題なく動いていました。
・ライトをベイクしない状態でビルドすると、エディタ上でもブラウザでも同じように表示されます。
・暗くなってる面はXYZそれぞれマイナス方向を向いてる面のような気がします。
・ライトのベイクのやり直しや、Unity、PCの再起動は何度かしてます。
・同様の作りになってる別シーン（以前ライトのベイク済み）をビルドすると問題無く動くので、ビルドに問題は無いと思います。
・しかし、同様の作りになってる別シーンに対し、改めてライティングのビルドを行うと、今回の暗くなる問題が起きました。（おそらくライトのビルドの問題？）
・Unityのバージョンは2021.1.1f1です。

①エディタ上では問題なし
[image: ①エディタ上では問題なし]

②ブラウザだと壁が暗い
[image: ②ブラウザだと壁が暗い]

③ビルド直後も暗い
[image: ③ビルド直後も暗い]

④クリックすると治る
[image: ④クリックすると治る]

ライトの設定
[image: ライトの設定]
[image: ライトの設定]

Answer (score 1):

Lightingの設定の「DirectionalMode」を「Non-Directional」に変更したところ解決いたしました。